# Make java.sql package or module available to boot classloader

Tags: java-9, module-path, classloading

I am using sql statement wrappers. When trying with jdk 11, I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/PreparedStatement. From java 9, java.sql is loaded in the platform loader. My wrapper classes are in boot classpath. How do I make any module to be available in the boot classpath.

I tried --add-modules java.sql It didn't work. Any suggestions

Comment: *"My wrapper classes are in boot classpath"* -> or module path? Do classes from class paths see classes from module paths?

Comment: Why are your wrapper classes in boot classpath? How did they get there? And why are they there?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by moving all my wrapper classes to system classpath